# Running a Cron job at some time in future, but only one time (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I have to send a email using cron job in laravel, the flow is that the user will select the time for the email to be sent. ones done, that email would be sent at that time but only ones, we dont have to send it again and again.

Comment: Batter to add some code describing how you implementing cronjob for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Laravels [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues), more specifically the [`Mailer::later`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#queueing-mail) and the [`Mailer::laterOn`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method_laterOn) method for that regard. You can delay the sending of the mail and it's only getting executed once.

```
YourMailable::later(now()->addMinutes(10))
```

or without a mailable:

```
Mail::later(now()->addMinutes(10), 'emails.view', $data, function ($message) {
    //
});
```

You can also specify a specifc queue within your Mailable:

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;

class YourMailable extends Mailable
{
    protected string $queue = 'mails-queue';

    // ...
}
```

With the Mail facade you can use the `laterOn` method:

```
Mail::laterOn('mails-queue', now()->addMinutes(10), 'emails.view', $data, function ($message) {
    //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch the job with the `delay` method.
For exampe this job will be run in one day from now:

```
dispatch(YourJob::class)->delay(now()->addDay());
```

Doc ref about delayed job https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching